# выбор selected в форме

Tags: php, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть страница с формой, где пользователь вводит дату. При нажатии на button, вычисляется нужные данные, но форма обнуляется. То есть в форме опять показываются первые значения select option.
Нужно, чтобы в выбранные пользователем option стали с атрибутом selected, после нажатия на button были опять показаны в форме.
Делаю так:

```
<option value="05" <?php if ($_POST["days"] == 5) {echo "selected";} ?>>5</option>
<option value="06" <?php if ($_POST["days"] == 6) {echo "selected";} ?>>6</option>
```

но слишком много строк, есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчёт выводить все эти строки в цикле?

```
<?

for ($i = 1; $i<=31; $i++) {
    ?><option value="<?=$i?>"<?
    if ($_POST["days"] === $i) {
        ?> selected<?
    }
    ?>><?=$i?></option><?
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сократить вот таким образом:

```
<option value="05" <?= $_POST["days"] == 5 ? "selected" : "" ?>>5</option>
```

В идеале должен быть "виджет", который бы принимал массив всех элементов, а некоторые из которых имели бы св-во "выбранный"
Например:

```
$elements = [
    ['value' => '05', 'selected' => false],
    ['value' => '06', 'selected' => true]
];
<?= Widget::dropDownList($elements);?>
```

Тогда метод `Widget::dropDownList` должен выводить тэг `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот такую схему приспособить под вашу задачу. Только в вашем случае список перебирать через foreach

```
$selected[$show]=' selected="selected"';

echo '<select name="show">'."\n";
echo '<option value="1"'.$selected['1'].'>Активен</option>'."\n";
echo '<option value="0"'.$selected['0'].'>Не активен</option>'."\n";
echo '</select>'."\n";
unset($selected);
```